# Problem with IPHLPAPI.DLL on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, regsvr32, regasm, dllregistration

I am trying to install an application which uses the API GetIPAddrfromTable stack. When I start up the application, I get the error "Procedure entry point not found in IPHLPAPI.dll"

I noticed that the dll file was quite old, so I tried replacing it, but Windows server 2008 doesn't let anyone copy any files to the system32 folder, even if you are administrator.

I tried to run sfc, and it updated the IPHLPAPI.DLL, and I tried to register the new DLL, but I get the error saying "The module iphlpapi.dll was loaded but the entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found. Make sure it is a valid DLL or OCX file".

I tried searching for the error messages, and they say something about using regasm, but I get the error "Error RA0000 : Failed to load because it is not a valid .NET assembly"

Is this a k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function, GetIpAddrTable() is the closest match.  Do *not* replace DLLs in c:\windows\system32, this can greatly destabilize Windows, assuming it would let you.  Iphlpapi.dll is a native DLL.  It cannot be registered with Regsvr32, it is not a COM component.  Nor can you use Regasm.exe, it is not a .NET assembly.

I have to guess that your [DllImport] declaration is simply wrong.  Consider using [this one](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetIpAddrTable.html).

Comment: Yes, I just had to copy the IPHLAPI.dll from another computer to the directory where the application was running from.